# jQuery mobile touch events not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using phone gap to develop cross platform mobile application.

Now if I am using Swipe events. They only works if it is the first page of the application like index.html .

But if I am redirecting if it is the second page

login --> Index.html

the swipe and links stop working

Not able to figure out the issue.Please help

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchstart', function() {
            // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
            doUnbind();
        });

        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('mousedown', function() {
            // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
            doUnbind();
        });

        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchend', function() {
            //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
            // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
            setTimeout(function() {
                doBind();
            }, 100);
        });

        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('mouseup', function() {
            //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
            // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
            setTimeout(function() {
                doBind();
            }, 100);
        });

        // Set the initial window (assuming it will always be #1
        window.now = 1;

        //get an Array of all of the pages and count
        windowMax = $('div[data-role="page"]').length;

        doBind();
    });
    // Functions for binding swipe events to named handlers
    function doBind() {
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swipeleft", turnPage);
        $('div[data-role="page"]').live("swiperight", turnPageBack);
    }

    function doUnbind() {
        $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swipeleft", turnPage);
        $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swiperight", turnPageBack);
    }

    // Named handlers for binding page turn controls
    function turnPage() {
        // Check to see if we are already at the highest numbers page            
        if (window.now < windowMax) {
            window.now++
            $.mobile.changePage("#device" + window.now, "slide", false, true);
        }
    }

    function turnPageBack() {
        // Check to see if we are already at the lowest numbered page
        if (window.now != 1) {
            window.now--;
            $.mobile.changePage("#device" + window.now, "slide", true, true);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="device1">
        <h1>School Day</h1>
        <p>Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan
            el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de
            "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este
            texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han
            evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras
            veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el
            estilo).</p>


    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="device2">
        <h1>School Day</h1>
        <p>TRichard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de
            Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras
            de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y
            al seguir leyendo distintos textos del latín, descubrió la fuente
            indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de
            "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por
            Cicero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un
            tratado de teoría de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: need to see if you are using ajax in some way.

Comment: @NDakotaBE if I am running it in eclipse browser also it is working fine.

Comment: @jai if I am running it in eclipse browser also it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have redone your code and made a working jsFiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/sBnyP/

It has been tested of desktop Firefox, Android 4.1.1 Chrome and iOS iPad 6.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#device1, #device2', function(){      
        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchstart mousedown', function() {
            // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
            doUnbind();
        });

        $('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchend mouseup', function() {
            //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
            // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
            setTimeout(function() {
                doBind();
            }, 100);
        });

        doBind();
    });

    // Functions for binding swipe events to named handlers
    function doBind() {
        $(document).on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', turnPage);      
        $(document).on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', turnPageBack);
    }

    function doUnbind() {
        $(document).off('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', turnPage);      
        $(document).off('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', turnPageBack);
    }

    // Named handlers for binding page turn controls
    function turnPage(event) {
            if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
            {    
                var nextpage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]'); 
                // swipe using id of next page if exists
                if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
                }
                event.handled = true;
            }
            return false;  
    }

    function turnPageBack(event) {
            if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
            {      
                var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
                //alert('Left');    
                if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
                }
                event.handled = true;
            }
            return false;  
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="device1">
        <h1>School Day</h1>
        <p>Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan
            el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de
            "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este
            texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han
            evolucionado a través de los anos, algunas veces por accidente, otras
            veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el
            estilo).</p>


    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="device2">
        <h1>School Day</h1>
        <p>TRichard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de
            Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras
            de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y
            al seguir leyendo distintos textos del latín, descubrió la fuente
            indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de
            "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por
            Cicero, escrito en el ano 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un
            tratado de teoría de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. All the things worked for me Actually when I am using window.location.href it is working but previous when I am using   $.mobile.changePage( ); it is not working . I have searched a allot but not understating why is it happening

Answer (score 0):

Instead this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

you should try this:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit',function() {
```

and this `should be pasted above jquery mobile script`.

So the order will be:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).on('pageinit',function() {
      /.....all the code here
 </script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
 </script>
```

Comment: No its not working on emulator and device both. It works with eclipse browser only.